# how do we create react classes dynamically?

Tags: class, reactjs, dynamic

Is there any feasible way of looping through the classes below  and rather than making one by one . Like can can A , B , C be mapped in a way such that they return the same statements as below ... ?

```
//individual similar classes 
var A = React.createClass({ ... });
var B = React.createClass({ ... });
var C = React.createClass({ ... });
var D = React.createClass({ ... });

//class that executes all these classes through map and return something along these lines    
[A,B,C,D] => [React.createClass({ ... }),React.createClass({ ... }),React.createClass({ ... }),React.createClass({ ... })]
```

Comment: Just curious, we do you want to do it this way?

Comment: use Higher Order Components, pass down classes to a component that do stuff to them and return again. If that's what you wanted, right?

Comment: @PraneshRavi : I had a lot of similar classes, I just wanted to see if we could create all those classes through a single class, using a loop.

Comment: @PooyaSanooei : Can u be specific.. which Higher Order Components ?

Comment: @Mihika http://reactpatterns.com/#Higher-order%20component